# issue while running docker -compose command

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

While running the following command for docker compose
docker -compose -f mongo.yaml up
I am getting the below mentioned error:
unable to resolve docker endpoint: context "ompose" does not exist

Comment: In your command, is there a space in `docker -compose`?  There shouldn't be, `docker-compose` is a single hyphenated word.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be an error with the command you're trying to run.

`docker-compose` is a separate binary. It should be invoked as
`docker-compose -f mongo.yaml`
Note the spacing. Docker compose is a separate tool and does not ship with Docker. Please install it if you have not already. Link to official docs:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Update: Recent versions of docker for some operating systems include docker-compose. Please check the official documentation (link above) for more information.